# ConnectionAbortedError on gevent using flask-socketio

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I'm using Flask with flask-socketio and with gevent, working with Windows.

The socket are working good but, when i change the page on the client web, on the terminal appears this gevent error:

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

this is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 935, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 909, in run_application
    self.process_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 895, in process_result
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 741, in write
    self._write_with_headers(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 763, in _write_with_headers
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 726, in _write
    self._sendall(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 701, in _sendall
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket3.py", line 418, in sendall
    data_sent += self.send(data_memory[data_sent:], flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socket3.py", line 390, in send
    return _socket.socket.send(self._sock, data, flags)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
Fri Dec 14 10:44:35 2018 {'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '56659', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:5000', (hidden keys: 23)} failed with ConnectionAbortedError
```

And this is my pip freeze :

```
asn1crypto==0.22.0
astroid==1.6.3
autopep8==1.3.5
Babel==2.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bleach==2.1.3
cairocffi==0.8.0
CairoSVG==2.1.3
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.3
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
crypto==1.4.1
cryptography==2.2.2
cssselect2==0.2.1
cycler==0.10.0
dateutils==0.6.6
decorator==4.0.11
defusedxml==0.5.0
dnspython==1.16.0
docutils==0.14
dxfgrabber==0.8.4
dxfwrite==1.2.1
entrypoints==0.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Babel==0.11.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-SocketIO==3.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
Flask-WeasyPrint==0.5
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
freeopcua==0.90.3
Genshi==0.7.1
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.13
hgapi==1.7.4
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.5
ipykernel==4.8.0
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.2.1
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
jedi==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.9.6
jsonpickle==0.9.4
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.2
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lxml==3.8.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==2.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.3
monotonic==1.5
mpmath==1.0.0
Naked==0.1.31
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
netifaces==0.10.6
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.4.1
numpy==1.14.2
openpyxl==2.4.9
pandas==0.22.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.1.1
pbr==3.0.1
pdfrw==0.4
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.0.0
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pycparser==2.17
Pygments==2.2.0
pylint==1.8.4
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
Pyphen==0.9.4
pypng==0.0.18
PyQRCode==1.2.1
PyQt5==5.8.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-engineio==3.0.0
python-hglib==2.6.1
python-socketio==2.1.1
pytz==2017.2
pywinpty==0.5.1
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.4
qtconsole==4.3.1
queuelib==1.5.0
requests==2.17.3
rope==0.10.7
rst2html5==1.9.4
scipy==1.0.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
shellescape==3.4.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
sip==4.19.2
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.10
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.3
svgwrite==1.1.11
sympy==1.1.1
Tempita==0.5.2
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
tinycss2==0.6.1
tornado==4.5.3
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.21.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
WeasyPrint==0.42
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
widgetsnbextension==3.2.1
wrapt==1.10.11
WTForms==2.1
xlrd==1.1.0
yolk3k==0.9
```

I can't find the solution, maybe the firewall it's killing the sockets if there are more than one? any idea? 
This problem doesn't stop the server but it's annoying.
thanks a lot

Comment: This is, I think, a problem with the Windows support in gevent. You may want to try eventlet in place of gevent.

Comment: You're right @Miguel, I've tried with eventlet and the error doesn't come out anymore. Thank you very much.
Thank you for your good work, it has been an honor to receive an answer from you.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg I got this error after 5 years and your comment fixed it...  Would you add this as an answer so others find it easier?